# Nested models, forms and date_select FormHelper integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, migration

I have followed Ryan Bates [tutorial](http://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-197/surveysays) on nested models.  Several of my nested models have dates associated with them.  In my migrations, they are actually the type "Date."

Some things I have tried and problems I've run into

1. date_select - **can handle the form object prefix, but not nested models attributes**
2. select_year - **doesn't work with form object**
3. a regular select populated with the year by using (Time.now.year - 100)..(Time.now.year) and overriding the attr accessor start_date and end_date to take the value in the select to form a date and passing that back.  **works on create only, not on update**
4. changing the data type of the field to string and using a regular select populated with the year by using using (Time.now.year - 100)..(Time.now.year) **works, but on edit, it won't repopulate the select with the current information**

Any ideas or hints would be helpful.

**Edit: before_save seems to be more promising but for some reason, the value is nil coming into before save but is visible in the [log dump.](http://pastie.org/private/e3u5eaqknemnmhnjxrepa)**

**Edit 2: Interestingly, this only seems to be a problem on 'update', not on 'create'.**

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution:

```
<% new_or_existing = task.new_record? ? 'new' : 'existing' %>
  <% prefix = "project[#{new_or_existing}_task_attributes][]" %>

<% fields_for prefix, task do |t| -%>
   <%= t.date_select(:start_date, :index => task.id || nil) %>
<% end -%>
```

Here's the explanation of why it works:

http://agilerails.wordpress.com/2009/03/11/date_select-time_select-doesnt-work-with-auto_prefix-object/

Answer (score 2):

I'd seriously hope that this works for date_select as well:

http://jeffperrin.com/2009/06/04/rails-nested-forms-and-collection_select/

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't.  You have to apply a bit of a hack to make it work.  <% date_select('attorney[memberships_attributes][NEW_RECORD]', "enddate", :start_year => 2015, :end_year => 1900, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :prompt => { :day => 'Day', :month => 'Month', :year => 'Year' }) %>. The 'attorney[memberships_attributes][NEW_RECORD]' is prefixed onto the select and then uses the correct attribute.  This works only if you are able to replace 'NEW_RECORD' at the time of creating the nested model, which isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work with the formtastic gem...